# PHP Sql query to multiple tables in MYSQL database - Needs professional touch

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following script works correctly however I don't like it because it isn't elegant and is just down right messy.

Without getting too advanced (meaning I don't want OOP style) I just want to minimize this code in a procedural fashion. Mainly I want to combine the SQL queries and clean up the mess.

```
//get page url and query db to find the correct page
$this_page = $_GET['page'];
$this_page = escape_data($_GET['page']);

//Make sure page exists - if it doesn't redirect the browser
$SQL_page_exist = "SELECT * FROM pages_learn_more WHERE page_title = '$this_page'";
$SPE_result = mysql_query($SQL_page_exist);

while ($details = mysql_fetch_array($SPE_result))
{
$page_id          =     $details['id'];
$page_title       =     $details['page_title'];
$main_title       =     $details['main_title'];
$main_content     =     $details['main_content'];
$sub_title        =     $details['sub_title'];
$sub_content      =     $details['sub_content'];    
}

if(mysql_num_rows($SPE_result) == 0) 
{
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=page_not_found.php">';

} else {

$SQL = 
    "SELECT   ptt.tool_tip_link
       FROM   pages_tool_tip ptt
       JOIN   pages_to_pages ptp
         ON   ptp.tool_tip_id = ptt.tool_tip_id
      WHERE   ptp.learn_more_id = '$page_id'";

  $result = mysql_query($SQL); // or die(mysql_error()); 

  //set array for reference_keys variable which may contain 0 to 20 keys
  $reference_keys = array();
  while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
 $reference_keys[] =     $db_field['tool_tip_link'];    
}
```

Ok so this above code works as it should, but it is very ugly and I have been trying for the past 2 hours to refine it into something clean, simple and beautiful, but alas my skills are not yet there and all i get is mysql errors.

My most recent attempt is:

```
$SQL = 
"
     SELECT     *
       FROM     pages_learn_more plm

       JOIN     pages_tool_tip ptt, pages_to_pages ptp 
         ON     ptp.tool_tip_id = ptt.tool_tip_id
      WHERE     plm.page_title = '$this_page' AND ptp.learn_more_id = plm.id 
";

$result = mysql_query($SQL); // or die(mysql_error()); 

$reference_keys = array();
while ($details = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
        $reference_keys[] =     $details['tool_tip_link'];  
        $page_id          =     $details['id'];
        $page_title       =     $details['page_title'];
        $main_title       =     $details['main_title'];
        $main_content     =     $details['main_content'];
        $sub_title        =     $details['sub_title'];
        $sub_content      =     $details['sub_content'];    
}
```

**This is like my 30th failed attempt to clean up this code. Can someone with knowledge please help me out and if possible please explain your input...

Thank you **

As a side note:
I even tried many queries in PHPmyAdmin, which taught me that the order of your tables in your SELECT of FROM statement will impact your result so for example `SELECT pages_learn_more plm, pages_tool_tip ptt` !=  `SELECT pages_tool_tip ptt, pages_learn_more plm`  And I don't understand how the order of these statements impacts the results. (When used in the full query 1 Will result in an error and the other Shows the tables)

PIC OF MY DATABASE SCHEME IF IT HELPS

[image]

Comment: The order matters because you have mixed an explicit `JOIN` with an implicit join (comma-separated tables) but you don't actually have a condition joining `plm` to the other two tables, which means you're getting a cartesian product.  Can you post your table structure? Then we can understand how the 3 tables fit together

Comment: I just did- Thanks @Michael -> I'm trying to build a many to many relationship - so would that be a cartesian product?

Comment: No, the many-to-many isn't the cause.  Any time you have a join without an ON clause, your result is the number of rows in table A * number of rows in table B. In some cases, if the WHERE clause limits one of them to only one row, this isn't a big problem, but if it isn't limited, you'll get many more rows than intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a strange mix of implicit (comma-separated tables) and explicit `JOIN`s, which affects the order the tables appear in.  Implicit joins are discouraged, so use only explicit ones.

Since you are not using all columns, do not `SELECT *`, especially since some tables have the same column names (`tool_tip_id`), which causes ambiguity.  Instead, be a little more explicit about what you're selecting.  You can even replace `plm.*` below with the exact list of columns you need from that table.

```
$SQL = 
"
     SELECT
       plm.*,
       ptt.tool_tip_link
     FROM
         pages_learn_more plm
         LEFT JOIN pages_to_pages ptp ON plm.id = ptp.learn_more_id
         LEFT JOIN pages_tool_tip ptt ON ptp.tool_tip_id = ptt.tool_tip_id
      WHERE
         plm.page_title = '$this_page'
";
```

In your while loop, the only columns you access are those of `pages_learn_more` and one from `pages_tool_tip`, so in the `SELECT` list, I used `plm.*` for all columns on that table, and `ptt.tool_tip_link` only from the other table.

Since your primary table appears to be `pages_learn_more` which may or may not have associated records in `pages_to_pages`, I substituted a `LEFT JOIN`, so even if it had no associated tool tip, the query could still return a record (with a NULL tooltip).

Technically, the second `LEFT JOIN` could just be an `INNER JOIN` since there must be a record in `pages_tool_tip` if one exists `pages_to_pages`.

Comment: Wow you just made that incredibly easy and I've been pulling my hair out over here for like 2 hours.. Thank you, If you have a moment can you please explain the logic why you chose those `SELECT`, why you structured your `FROM` like that and your `WHERE` as such. I'm really trying to be a good programmer but reading a book tells me how to do something but never really explains why to do it in that way.. I'm very grateful for your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @FabioAnselmo A little more explanation added.  The only changes I made to the WHERE were line break formatting. I find it easier to understand when indented that way, so multiple `AND` conditions are each listed on a new line. Same thing with joined tables, each on a new line, indented in from the `FROM` clause. But none of this is _standard_, just common practice.

Comment: your explanation is worth it's weight in GOLD! The `pages_tool_tip` and `pages_to_pages` tables are both set to NULL. Some pages don't have any `tool_tip_link` associations and I'm finding that nothing is returned for those pages. Meaning I don't get `page_title` or `main_title`, etc. from the `pages_learn_more` table. So from your explanation I figured changing the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` would do the trick but it had no effect. What am I over looking? Additionally I changed `plm.*` to `plm.id, plm.page_title, plm.main_title, plm.main_content, plm.sub_title, plm.sub_content`

Comment: @FabioAnselmo I just noticed that there _was_ the other join condition as a where clause component, which turns the left join into an inner join. ( I should look more closely). Take out the second part of the `WHERE` clause as I did above and you should get the rows that have no associations back.

Comment: You sir are amazing! So basically any time you `AND` a query in a `WHERE` statement that will always == an `INNER JOIN`, which by default `INNER JOINS` look for associations and thus break the script if their aren't any? Is my interpretation accurate of how `INNER JOINS` work with multiple `WHERE` queries? Thanks again Michael.

Comment: No, not any `AND` condition, only if you do `table1.id = table2.id` in the `WHERE` clause (equivalent to `INNER JOIN`), which is what you had, _in addition_ to the `LEFT JOIN` that I put in the `FROM`. So your original query did have all the join conditions, they were just spread around the FROM & WHERE.  If there are missing associations, no row is returned by the inner join.

Comment: @FabioAnselmo Read [this truly excellent article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) by Jeff Atwood, founder of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

1) this section is suspect.

```
while ($details = mysql_fetch_array($SPE_result))
{
    $page_id          =     $details['id'];
     ...
}
```

Are you expecting more than one result?  If so, why not modify the query to return exactly the result you require. You could use LIMIT 1, ORDER BY {field} DESC, WHERE ...,  etc.
If you are expecting only one result, use an if instead of a while.

2) this condition should be moved up before the data extraction.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($SPE_result) == 0) 
{
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=page_not_found.php">';

} else {
    ... move your mysql_fetch_array($SPE_result) here, and you don't need a conditional for it.
```

3) "and all i get is mysql errors"

What errors are you getting?

Comment: thanks for your input, please review Michael's answer. He hit the nail on the HEAD!